# Provide anonymous download on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, anonymous

I have a vanilla install of Apache/2.2.20 running on Ubuntu 11.10. I would like to provide two files that can be accessed anonymously (a readme.html and a 1.7GB download).

I would like use Google Analytics to track visits to `myserver/readme.html`, but provide an alternate path `myserver/private/readme.html` and `myserver/private/bigdownload` that is not tracked by Google Analytics or recorded in an Apache log.

My goals are in line with [a standard requirements of scientific review](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/static/guidelines.action), namely, that I provide anonymous download access. There are so few potential reviewers that even knowing the state or country could compromise anonymity.

I have thought of a few potential solutions but I relatively unfamiliar with Apache and web-server configuration:

1. stop Apache from loging source ip addresses and/or other identifyable information for a specific directory (but, how?)?
2. configure Google Analytics to ignore a sub-path (how?)
3. find an anonymous browser that can hide location.

What is the easiest way to provide anonymous download access from a server?

Comment: Have you considered just hosting the file on some 3rd party site where you don't have access to the metrics?  I would suggest megaupload, but ...  There are alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your httpd.conf file

```
<Directory /usr/local/www/myserver/private/>
    LogFormat "%f"
</Directory>
```

This will change the logged line to just the file name. So you'll have a record saying that it was downloaded, but no other record in the log file of who downloaded it or even the exact time.

Comment: Looks promising, but after `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, I get the following error: `Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
LogFormat not allowed here
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!` (nothing recent in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

Answer (score 2):

Run a separate VirtualHost that disables access logging.